# How to have different mandatory parameters for two categories using argparse python?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I am working on python script where I need to do two things basis on the input parameters passed:

- **push:** This will call an api to post some data.
- **status:** This will call another api to check the data and print out details on the console.

When we use `push` parameter then we need to always pass these three mandatory parameters:

- **environment**
- **instance**
- **config**

And when we use `status` parameter then we need to pass only these two mandatory parameters:

- **environment**
- **instance**

How can I make these arguments configurable in such a way using `argparse` in Python? I was reading more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) but confuse on how to make above things work in nice way? Also usage message should clearly tell what to use with what input.

Is this possible to do using `argparse`? Any example will be greatly appreciated. In general we will call a method for `push` case which will use those parameters and similarly for `status` we will call some other method which will use those parameters.

Comment: Yes, I think you want to use 'subcommands' in the 'argparse' module.  Here's a pointer to the section of the docs that covers them.  This is probably in the same docs (different version maybe) that you link above, but it will take you right to the subcommand section: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: Personally, before someone goes all trigger happy about possible duplicate this or duplicate that, this is the first time I've seen a clear minimalist example for argparse subcommands that doesn't just "refer to docs" or, opposite end, write a novel about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that uses argparse with two subcommands:

```
"""
How to have different mandatory parameters for two categories
using argparse python?
"""
import argparse
import sys

def main():
    """
    Description here
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Stack Overflow 64995368 Parser'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-v",
        "--verbose",
        help="verbose output",
        action="store_true"
    )
    subparser = parser.add_subparsers(
        title="action",
        dest='action',
        required=True,
        help='action sub-command help'
    )

    # create the subparser for the "push" command
    parser_push = subparser.add_parser(
        'push',
        help='push help'
    )
    parser_push.add_argument(
        'environment',
        type=str,
        help='push environment help'
    )
    parser_push.add_argument(
        'instance',
        type=str,
        help='push instance help'
    )
    parser_push.add_argument(
        'config',
        type=str,
        help='push config help'
    )

    # create the subparser for the "status" command
    parser_status = subparser.add_parser(
        'status',
        help='status help'
    )
    parser_status.add_argument(
        'environment',
        type=str,
        help='status environment help'
    )
    parser_status.add_argument(
        'instance',
        type=str,
        help='status instance help'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.action == 'push':
        print('You chose push:',
            args.environment, args.instance, args.config)
    elif args.action == 'status':
        print('You chose status:',
            args.environment, args.instance)
    else:
        print('Something unexpected happened')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nCaught ctrl+c, exiting")
```

Example output for various command lines:

```
$ python3 test.py
usage: test.py [-h] [-v] {push,status} ...
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: action
```

---

```
$ python3 test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-v] {push,status} ...

Stack Overflow 64995368 Parser

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose output

action:
  {push,status}  action sub-command help
    push         push help
    status       status help
```

---

```
$ python3 test.py push -h
usage: test.py push [-h] environment instance config

positional arguments:
  environment  push environment help
  instance     push instance help
  config       push config help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

---

```
$ python3 test.py push
usage: test.py push [-h] environment instance config
test.py push: error: the following arguments are required: environment, instance, config
```

---

```
$ python3 test.py push myenv
usage: test.py push [-h] environment instance config
test.py push: error: the following arguments are required: instance, config
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, using [`set_defaults`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) to attribute a handler for each subcommand.

```
import argparse

def push(args):
    return (args.environment, args.instance, args.config)

def status(args):
    return (args.environment, args.instance)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# create the parser for the push command
push_parser = subparsers.add_parser('push')
push_parser.set_defaults(func=push)

push_parser.add_argument('--environment', type=str)
push_parser.add_argument('--instance', type=str)
push_parser.add_argument('--config', type=str)


# create the parser for the status command
status_parser = subparsers.add_parser('status')
status_parser.set_defaults(func=status)

status_parser.add_argument('--environment', type=str)
status_parser.add_argument('--instance', type=str)

    
args = parser.parse_args(['push', '--environment=a', '--instance=b', '--config=c'])
print(args.func(args))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often easier just to use sys.argv contents directly.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
s_args  = sys .argv  ##  s_args[0] = script_name.py

def push( environment,  instance,  config ):
    print( 'PUSH command:',  environment,  instance,  config )

def status( environment,  instance ):
    print( 'STATUS command:',  environment,  instance )

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len( s_args ) < 4:
        print( 'missing args:' )
        print( '    PUSH environment instance config' )
        print( '    STATUS environment instance' )

    elif s_args[1] .lower() == 'push':
        if len( s_args ) < 5:
            print( 'missing args for PUSH command:' )
            print( '    PUSH environment instance config' )
        else:
            push( s_args[2],  s_args[3],  s_args[4] )

    elif s_args[1] .lower() == 'status':
        if len( s_args ) < 4:
            print( 'missing args for STATUS command:' )
            print( '    STATUS environment instance' )
        else:
            status( s_args[2],  s_args[3] )

    else:
        print( 'incorrect command:' )
        print( '    PUSH environment instance config' )
        print( '    STATUS environment instance' )
```